# Animation performance decreasing overtime

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to create a 2d HTML canvas animation with KineticJS.
An image is loaded to html5 canvas as background, and am trying to move it horizontally.
Initially the code is running fine. After few seconds, the moving speed reduces and starts to stuck and finally chrome/firefox will stop responding.

```
var CanvasXSize = 800;
var CanvasYSize = 600;
var speed = 30; //lower is faster
var scale = 1.05;
var y = -4.5; //vertical offset

var dx = 0.75;
var imgW;
var imgH;
var x = 0;
var clearX;
var clearY;

var tempImage = new Kinetic.Image();

var stage;
var backgroundLayer;
var img;

var initialize = function(){

img = new Image();
img.src = 'movingBack.jpg'; // image of size 3000x600

stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 800,
    height: 600
});

backgroundLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

img.onload = function() {
    imgW = img.width*scale;
    imgH = img.height*scale;
    if (imgW > CanvasXSize) { x = CanvasXSize-imgW; } // image larger than canvas
    if (imgW > CanvasXSize) { clearX = imgW; } // image larger than canvas
    else { clearX = CanvasXSize; }
    if (imgH > CanvasYSize) { clearY = imgH; } // image larger than canvas
    else { clearY = CanvasYSize; }
    //Set Refresh Rate
    return setInterval(draw, speed);
  }
 }

function draw() {
//Clear Canvas
backgroundLayer.clear(0,0,clearX,clearY);
//If image is <= Canvas Size
if (imgW <= CanvasXSize) {
    //reset, start from beginning
    if (x > (CanvasXSize)) { x = 0; }
    //draw additional image
    if (x > (CanvasXSize-imgW))
    {
        backgroundLayer.add(new Kinetic.Image(
        {
            x: CanvasXSize+1,
            y: y,
            image: img,
            width: imgW,
            height: imgH
        }
        ));
        stage.add(backgroundLayer);
    }
}
//If image is > Canvas Size
else {
    //reset, start from beginning
    if (x > (CanvasXSize)) { x = CanvasXSize-imgW; }
    //draw additional image
    if (x > (CanvasXSize-imgW))
    {
        backgroundLayer.add(new Kinetic.Image(
            {
                x: x-imgW+1,
                y: y,
                image: img,
                width: imgW,
                height: imgH
            }
        ));
        stage.add(backgroundLayer);
    }
}
//draw image
backgroundLayer.add(new Kinetic.Image(
    {
        x: x,
        y: y,
        image: img,
        width: imgW,
        height: imgH
    }
));
stage.add(backgroundLayer);
//amount to move
x += dx;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you add lot of new layers in a loop, and .clear() doesnt remove them from draw queue. Add those images/layers once and then operate on them when moving, etc.